# Flutter connectivity:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Flutter project and it's work on other systems successfully.
now I'm new in the team and today I pulled the project on my PC.
Unfortunately, I got an error and cant build the project.

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
error: warnings found and -Werror specified

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':connectivity:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[image]

[image]

anybody can help me!?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is related to your SDK version. Please upgrade it.

Comment: actually i up/down grade later

Answer (score 0):

In your android/build.gradle File

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0"
    ...
}
}
```

And also add  In your android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

Taken from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67996#issuecomment-707696255

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to shift to `connectivity_plus` instead of `connectivity` as it might not be properly supported

[Here](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) is the installation guide

If not then please check the issues thread as above, most probably it is an issue with your setup